# AgGrid dropdown custom filter fed with columns values

Tags: typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a custom floating filter with agGrid, the column is declared as follow :

```
field: "companyName",
filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
sort: "asc",
sortable: true,
floatingFilterComponent: SupplierNameFilter,
floatingFilterComponentParams: {
    suppressFilterButton: true,
},
```

And my filter component :

```
export default forwardRef((props: IFloatingFilterParams, ref ) => {
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState<DropdownOption>({
    text: 'All',
    value: 'undefined'
  });
  const [filterOptions, setFilterOptions] = useState<DropdownOption[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const displayedCompanies  = //How do i get all the values displayed in the companyName column ?;
    setFilterOptions(displayedCompanies)

  }, [props])

  return (
    <ListFilterOptions
      activeOption={currentValue}
      options={filterOptions}
      onOptionSelected={(o) => {
        setCurrentValue(o);
      }}
    />
  );
});
```

ListFilterOption is a component that displays a dropdown list, options represent

The filter component displays a custom dropdown list, but it tries to imitate the behavior of an AgGrid setFilter where the filter's available options depend on the values displayed in the given column.
So if the `companyName` column had two rows with `Nike` and `Adidas` the filter would display those two companies, but if `Adidas` is chosen in the filter, the the grid is filtered and `Nike` is "removed" from the grid so then the filter would display `Adidas`

How do i get a list of all the values displayed for the column ?
I tried to use `getRenderedNodes` but it did not help